# Ubuntu 15.04 : The save button in the 802.1x security is disabled when you choose PEAP in Authenication in network setting

Tags: networking, connection

The save button is disbaled when the PEAP in the authentication is choosed in the Network Connection  ---> 802.1x Security. because of this I'm not able to connect to my network

Answer (score 2):

In the CA Certificate Field mark the option "NO CA Certificate is Required" and in the anonymous identity field write your identity.That will make the save button enable.